# VLC fails to play mpeg-2 correctly

Tags: vlc, mpeg-2

My friend has a problem with playing `mpeg-2` files correctly with his VLC player.

Audio is playing fluently, but video is fitful. He tried to play same files with Windows Media Player, so he knows that files are OK. Files are stored on SSD disk in his computer that has no problem with data transmition.

Reinstalling VLC and codecs was ineffective.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the cache settings inside of VLC.

All it needed was **total** reinstall (including deleting of all settings).